# Update Selectize Input without reset in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a selectInput where I can choose anything between `a` and `e`.

I want to have a button which adds automatically `a`,`b`, and `e` to the selection if I click on it.

*Problem:*
I don't want it to reset the already selected items in the input.

For example, the user already selected `a` and `d`, then he clicks on the button. Instead of getting `a`, `b` and `e`, I want the user to get `a`,`b`,`d`, and `e` because he already selected `a` and `d`.

*Question:*
How can I modify the `updateSelectInput()` so it doesn't reinitialize everytime, but just adds the choices to the already selected other ones that aren't already chosen, here only add `b` and `e` and not resetting" to just `a`,`b`, and `e`?

## Code:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("Yo"),

sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
     uiOutput("select"),
     actionButton("clear","Adding new")
  ),
  
 mainPanel(
     
   )
 )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
 output$select <- renderUI({
  selectizeInput("sel", "The choices",choices = c("a","b","c","d","e"), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE,options = list())
 
})
observeEvent (input$clear,{
 updateSelectizeInput(session,"sel", selected = c("a","b","e"), options = list())
 
 })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well once again I'm dumb and it was a pretty easy fix,

you just have to get the preselected arguments in a variable and add it to the selected in the update :

```
observeEvent (input$clear,{
  edit <- input$sel
  updateSelectizeInput(session,"sel", selected = c(edit,"a","b","e"), options = list())
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for putting this as an answer because I cannot comment. I am still not clear with your question kindly provide image of what you want, so that it becomes more clear. And will be more than happy to solve your question.

Thanks :)